# How to write in an open PPTX using Python

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have written some code using the `python-pptx` package that allows me to save my plots to the slides of a powerpoint. Unfortunately the function `pptx.save('plots.pptx')` throws an error if I have the presentation open at the same time:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'plots.pptx'`

If the file is closed, the code works like a charm and adds the plots to new slides as intended. But is there a way to be able to also save the plots to the presentation when I have it open?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. Powerpoint puts a lock on a file when it opens it, so other processes can't write to it. One possible way around it is to open the file for writing in Python first, then try to open it in Powerpoint in read-only mode, but obviously you won't be able to make changes to it. Only one process can have a file open for writing at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

As MattDMo already wrote Powerpoint creates a look on the file. You could create a copy of the presentation and store it there.